# TextView SetText

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a problem.
In line "`textView.setText(money + "$");`" my program crashes.
(`money` is `int`, and `textView1` is `ID` of my `TextView`)

```
public TextView textView;
public void onCashClick(View view) {
    money++;
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(money + "$");
}
```

Comment: And what exception do you get? Post the error logcat.

Comment: Agreed, can you post the logcat? And where is `money` first declared?

Comment: In other clashh

Comment: And error is when i click on this button

Comment: And error is when i click on this button **Sorry, aplication MyApllication2 is stopped**

Comment: Can you please post the entire source code for this class, and the class where `money` is declared? Can you also post the logcat giving details of the crash? It's difficult to help without this information.

Comment: Initialize your `textView` in `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line makes your app crash. Because the view sent from the click is the button, not the container. Therefore, the button doesn't contain your textview. You should be getting NullPointerException on that line. Instead, you should define textView on onCreate method:

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

and only after, onCashClick call:

on button click.

UPDATE: change your code to the following,

```
public TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   }

public void onCashClick(View view) {
        money++;
        textView.setText(money + "$");
    }
```

Comment: When you write ( int + "string") there isn't different with ( valueOf(int) + "string" )

Comment: Again my application is crash. :(

Comment: Concatenating an int with a String implicitly converts that into into a String. This would make no difference.

Comment: And this is not working when i write only "textView.setText("text");"

Comment: @HubertHubert because you have to define textView outside that method, for instance, in onCreate method. Can you also share your onCreate method?

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        (...)
        public TextView testxxd;
    } Modifier "public" is not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

Cause the view you are using for binding the text view is the clicked button, instead of using view.findViewById() if your are in a activity just use findViewById and if your are in a fragment use your rootView.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `view` that is before findViewByID to be like this

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: this make sense

Comment: @HubertHubert what it gives you

Comment: Change text in my TextView